# Centralizing CloudStorageAccount and TableServiceContext instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

In an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Role, I have realized that I have been writing the below code a lot:

```
var account = 
    CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataConnectionString")
    );

var ctx = 
    account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetDataServiceContext();
```

So, I decided to Centralize this for the entire ASP.NET MVC application and I created the below class with static properties:

```
internal class WindowsAzureStorageContext {

    public static CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { 

        get {
            return
                CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                    RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataConnectionString")
                );
        }
    }

    public static TableServiceContext TableServiceCtx { 
        get {

            return
                StorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetDataServiceContext();
        } 
    }
}
```

And, I am using this as below inside my controllers:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private readonly TableServiceContext ctx = 
        WindowsAzureStorageContext.TableServiceCtx;

    public ViewResult Index() {

        var model = ctx.CreateQuery<TaskEntity>(Constants.TASKS_TABLE).
            Where(x => x.PartitionKey == string.Empty);

        return View(model);
    }

    public ViewResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("Create")]
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ViewResult Create_post(TaskEntity taskEntity) {

        ctx.AddObject(Constants.TASKS_TABLE, new TaskEntity(taskEntity.Task));
        ctx.SaveChangesWithRetries();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I know that this is not a unit test friendly and I should reach out that `TableServiceContext` instance through a interface by DI but when I do that, I consider using this `WindowsAzureStorageContext` class as well to get an instance of `TableServiceContext` class.

Is this a good practice? Would it hurt me in any point because I am using the same class for the entire application life-cycle?

Is there any know pattern to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with doing that.  Looks like a nice clean way to do it.  I don't know of a known pattern to do this but was just thinking there should be yesterday.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I asked this question is that I am not capable of the full features of `static` keyword. I was thinking if I would end up with problems if I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use repository pattern for a generic data context, with a generic interface on top of it. Not sure if it helps but you can refer my blog http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2010/03/15/azure-ndash-part-5-ndash-repository-pattern-for-table-service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any shared state between instances of the context. With that said, the transaction time for the controller to execute is non-trivial. The longer you hold onto the context, the more likely you are to get conflicts. I've found that one way to keep conflicts and overlaps to a minimum is to keep the load/change/save cycle as short as possible.

Erick